# Difference between $x and x($geometry)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, geometry, coordinates

I just stumbled across something weird: I had point-data in EPSG:3059 and wanted to add the coordinates to the attribute table using `$x` resp. `$y` - which returned `NULL`. `x($geometry)` on the other hand worked out.

Which leads me to the question: What exactly is the difference between the two functions?

Comment: it returned `NULL`

Comment: Are you working on non-point features, such as lines? `x($geometry)` can take centroids, while `$x` cannot.

Comment: Nope, it's point data, though styled as ellipsoids.

Comment: maybe it's multipoint?

Comment: No, we created the data ourselves, every point has its own ID etc.

Comment: Okay, following advice by @ahmadhanb I loaded the data into an empty GIS and discovered that the person who created the data actually created ellipsoids instead of points styled as ellipsoids - so no wonder why `$x` didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with point data, the results of both expressions of `$x` and `x($geometry)` are identical. Same applied to `$y` and `y($geometry)`. I tested the behavior of both expressions on my point grid data and I found that both them produced the same results as you can see below:

[image]

In the table above the coordinates in X and Y fields were calculated using the expressions `$x` and `$y`, respectively, whereas `x($geometry)` and `y($geometry)` were used to calculate the coordinates in X1 and Y1 fields, respectively.

As you can see, both produced the same results. For your reference I used QGIS 3.4.11-Madeira, and the CRS of the data is `WGS 84 / UTM zone 54N` (`EPSG:32654`).

I am not sure why you got NULL results when you used `$x` and `$y` but successful results with `x($geometry)` and `y($geometry)`, maybe something wrong happened in the QGIS project. My advice is to try loading the point data into a new QGIS project and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - the issue was that my colleague created polygons without me knowing about it - so `$x` naturally couldn't work out.

Comment: @Erik That makes sense of why $x didn’t work.